# Strange behaviour in function returning a list or a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

In the following code, if the `else` block is commented out, the type of the iterable object in the main function is a `list`. On the other hand, if I leave the `else` code (which I guess shouldn' be executed anyway) the `iterable` variable becomes a generator.

```
def gimme_an_iterable():
    my_list = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
    if True:
        return my_list
    else:
        for i in my_list:
            yield i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    iterable = gimme_an_iterable()
    print(type(iterable))
```

I'm using python3

Comment: The `return` is here seen as a way to *stop* the generator.

Comment: Of course it becomes a generator. Wether or not a function is a generator function is determined *at compile time*. You used `yield` in the function body, ergo it is a generator function.

Comment: See the [`yield` expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions): *Using a yield expression in a function’s body causes that function to be a generator[.]*